# Add alias to SqlAlchemy join object

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I am trying to select a column from a subquery (code below).

```
    import sqlalchemy as sa

    table1 = sa.schema.Table('t1',
                                 db,
                                 autoload=True,
                                 autoload_with=db.engine)
    si = Query().cte()

    pids = sa.select([t1.c.pid], distinct=True).where(t1.c.date > date)

    jt = pids.join(
            si,
            (si.c.pid == t1.c.pid) &
            (si.c.startdate <= date) &
            (si.c.enddate > date))
    return sa.select([si.c.id]).select_from(jt)
```

However, I always get an error like:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) subquery in FROM must have an alias
LINE 6: FROM (SELECT DISTINCT t1.pid AS pid 
             ^
HINT:  For example, FROM (SELECT ...) [AS] foo.
```

How should I add an alias to my subquery?

Comment: Your subquery needs to be a valid SQL statement.  SQL statements include `from` clauses, which is where you'd alias things.

Comment: Use [`.alias()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.Join.alias)?

Comment: @DavidT.Macknet In SQLAlchemy the `FROM` clause is inferred from the `SELECT` list if `FROM` is not specified.